# Cocoa: open URL in safari and force to start download content from the URL

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to open some video URLs in Safari, like `https://...../video.mp4`, this can be done via `NSWorkspace.openURL`.

But I also want to start download video in Safari once the URL finish loading (something like automatically perform the shortcut `Option + Enter` on the web search field), instead of watching the video online.

To be clear, I just want to build a simple app for myself that request Safari to download a bunch of videos from my indicated URLs, by one click. I didn't meant to make a downloader app from scratch

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The solution is simple: you just append the query `dl=1` (short version of download=true I guess) to the video URL you want to download instead of watching online. Like this: `https://...../video.mp4?dl=1`

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLSession to download the files directly. It's what Safari uses under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I’d like to let Safari manage the entire download process (default store path, pause and resume etc) for me.

Comment: There's no API for that. Also, it is bad user experience to jump the user too much between applications. -openURL: is intended for handing off control to another application completely. It is not intended to be a shortcut to writing proper download code, and therefore has no "download finished" callbacks. You can use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains() to get the current download folder, and NSURLSession to download & resume.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But to be clear, I just want to build a simple app for myself that request Safari to download a bunch of videos from my indicated URLs, by one click. I didn't meant to make a downloader app from scratch.

Comment: Have you looked at NSURLSession's API? You create an NSURLDownloadTask, give it the URL to download and a file URL to download to, call `resume()`, and it does the rest.

Comment: Yea I kinda know how to use NSURLSession. I just... don't think it worth the time to make custom user interfaces around that. I have scripts to fetch URLs for all WWDC sessions (100+ videos per year, each video takes about 1~3GB), things could quickly going mess up if I just use a simple NSURLSession wrapper to download them.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://...../video.mp4"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
self.downloadTask = [self.urlSession downloadTaskWithRequest:downloadRequest];
[self.downloadTask resume];
```